# How can I import my contacts and data from Basecamp to Proofhub?

Tags: import, data

I've been using [Basecamp](https://basecamp.com) as a project management tool since 2010.

It has a good interface and organisation of data, but sometimes you might not be willing to share the secrecy of a project with the clients. There is no such feature in Basecamp. That's why I am thinking to switch on [Proofhub](http://www.proofhub.com).

So, anybody please let me know is there any provision in Proofhub to import all the data and contact?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform following steps to import data from basecamp to your proofhub account.

Go to

1. Settings tab
2. Proofhub settings
3. Import tab
4. You have an option there whether you want to import from basecamp next.
5. After selecting the appropriate option fill your basecamp details and then click on import project.
6. All your data will be transferred to your new home for project management. For more information you can follow at http://help.proofhub.com/account/import-basecamp/